# actionlib axclient always disconnected from server

Tags: ros-melodic, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to run an action using my computer as a client and a robot as a server. I am using the actionlib axclient for that.
In my computer I can see the topic I want to use

```
rostopic info /navigation_wp/goal
Type: navigation_wp/NavigateActionGoal

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /navigation_wp (http://<robot_host>:39727/)
```

However when I use the axclient it always says that I am disconnected from the client and I can not send any goal

```
rosrun actionlib axclient.py /navigation_wp/goal
```

See picture attached
[C:\fakepath\axclient.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/161787872658316.png)

Also, I have checked that my bashrc is correctly set

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://192.168.0.42:11311"
```

which is the IP of the robot

Any clue?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375695/actionlib-axclient-always-disconnected-from-server/) by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2021-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced a similar issue on ROS Noetic.

I noticed my server nodes were advertized as `http://<HOST_NAME>:<portname>`
I didnt look into the cause of the problem but defining a `ROS_IP` on my server so that the nodes show up as `http://<HOST_IP>:<portname>`. (I do not remember if I had to set a ROS_IP on the client as well, so maybe you'll need to do that too).

Maybe this will solve your problem too ?

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2021-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) on 2021-04-21**:
yes, the problem was the ip on the server. Thanks!